# The product of the two positive definite matrices

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, optimal-control, nonlinear-dynamics, adaptive-control

I met a problem in Lyapunov stability proof:

$\dot{V}\leq -c\delta^T\bigg[\mathbb{T}\bigg((\mathbb{L}+G)\otimes(BR^{-1}B^T)\bigg)\bigg]\delta $

where $\mathbb{T}$ is a symmetric and positive definite matrix. $(\mathbb{L}+G)$ is a positive definite and non-symmetric matrix. $(BR^{-1}B^T)$ is a symmetric and positive definite matrix. $c>0$.  $\delta$ is state error vector (tracking problem).

My question is how can I continue to work on that to claim that $\dot{V}<0$?

thanks

Jie

Comment: What does $\otimes$ mean in this context?

Comment: @amsmath  Kronecker product,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: What does it mean for a non-symmetric matrix to be positive definite? The definition I'm familiar with as well as [the one in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) require symmetry. Do you mean the requirement that the *real part* of $z^*Mz$ is positive for all complex vectors $z$ as in [generalization section in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Extension_for_non-Hermitian_square_matrices)?

Comment: @ Adam Zalcman:  Yes, I am stuck here. Since I can not claim that the term inside the bracket to be positive definite, so I can not continue to claim that the $\dot{V}<0$. You mention that property requires symmetry.

Comment: Counterexample: for $\mathbb{T}=\mathrm{diag}(1, 6)$, $\mathbb{L}+G=\begin{bmatrix}5 & -2\\-4& 5\end{bmatrix}$, $BR^{-1}B^T = [1]$ and $\delta=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$, we get $$\delta^T\left[\mathbb{T}\left((\mathbb{L}+G)\otimes(BR^{-1}B^T)\right)\right]\delta = -2$$ where it is easy to check that all matrices are positive definite. I assume that $M$ is defined to be positive definite if $x^TMx>0$ for all real vectors $x$. It could be that they use a different definition of positive definiteness or that there is a quatifier somewhere that makes all relevant RHS include zero.